# How to query a model with an one-to-one association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to find all cards (belong to a user) where `next_review` is before current time `Time.zone.now`.

Below is my mode,

[image]

**Expect Behavior**

I should keep my finder method inside the corresponding model,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards
  def next_cards
    cards.next_cards
  end
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :meta
  def next_cards
    # what should I write here?
  end
end

class Meta < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :card
  # what should I write here?
end
```

**What I am thinking**

1. query meta table where(next_repetition < today)  inside `meta` model and get all target meta(s)
2. join (1) results to card table, to find the targets cards  inside `card` model
3. return target cards inside `user` model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user.cards.joins(:meta).where('metas.next_review_date <= ?', Time.zone.now)
```

***Update***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards
  def next_cards
    cards.next
  end
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :meta
  scope :next, -> { joins(:meta).merge(Meta.next) }
end

class Meta < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :card
  scope :next, -> { where('next_review_date <= ? ', Time.zone.now) }
end
```

Then

```
user.next_cards
```

will return only cards, which belong to user, and which have meta with review_date <= now

That will perform only 1 query, instead of 2-3 queries as you suggested in your post.

Comment: does it possible to separate this query to the model where it belongs to?

Comment: Sure. Actually I think it could be better to separate this function to the Card scope (instead of function), like: `scope :next_cards, -> { joins(:meta).where('metas.next_review_date <= ?', Time.zone.now) }`, then nothing else should be changed inside other models.

Comment: if I need to pass a limit where is a good place to do so? the limit might be a specific number or nil (which return all). Thank you so much for the response.

Comment: Better do not put it inside model and its scopes, because this is a value, that will probably be different inside different parts of your project. You can put it inside a controller action, just call `@user.next_cards.limit(10)`.

Comment: Thanks again! You are fantastic!